# What does 'the property-based notion of right'?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Specifically, what does ***property*** mean in the context? Does it mean ***possessions*** or ***attributes(qualities)***? To me, it is not clear in the context.

> Articulating the scope of this right is hard, not only do we have to
> take into account changing expectations and the government's
> increasing need to tackle crime and terrorism, but we also soon bump
> up against other people's human rights which also have to be
> respected. The right to privacy may extend only to the point where it
> does not unreasonably or disproportionately restrict someone else’s
> right to freedom of expression or right to information. However, when
> we move away from ***the property-based notion of a right*** (where
> the right to privacy would protect,  for example, images and
> personality), to modern notions of private and family life, we find it
> easier to delimit the right. This is, of course, the strength of the
> notion of privacy, in that it can adapt to meet changing expectations
> and technological advances involving data storage, telephone hacking,
> mass surveillance technology for emails, websites visits and telephone
> calls, digital images, and DNA identification.

[Human Rights: A Very Short Introduction](https://books.google.co.kr/books?id=6MKPCgAAQBAJ&pg=PA114&lpg=PA114&dq=However,%20when%20we%20move%20away%20from%20the%20property-based%20notion%20of%20a%20right%20(where%20the%20right%20to%20privacy%20would%20protect,%20for%20example,%20images%20and%20personality),%20to%20modern%20notions%20of%20private%20and%20family%20life,%20we%20find%20it&source=bl&ots=66F6uwq6re&sig=ACfU3U0a9Fvd_Yd0pHvwNbCMqcej5R5x6w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjoptKk06TxAhU5wosBHbx2CeMQ6AEwAHoECAIQAw#v=onepage&q=However%2C%20when%20we%20move%20away%20from%20the%20property-based%20notion%20of%20a%20right%20(where%20the%20right%20to%20privacy%20would%20protect%2C%20for%20example%2C%20images%20and%20personality)%2C%20to%20modern%20notions%20of%20private%20and%20family%20life%2C%20we%20find%20it&f=false)

Answer (score 1):

Property-based rights would be rights based on ownership of something. For example, if you own a house, you have the right to 'enjoy' (ie live in) your property. There are also less-tangible but equally valid rights of ownership, such as copyrights.

What this text is saying is that, rights are more easily respected when ownership is involved. If someone loses something that they own, that is a clear infringement of rights. But if rights are not so readily noticeable, some find it more acceptable to infringe upon them.

Answer (score 0):

It means a notion of "rights" based on **ownership**.